# Alignment is off

Tags: subequations

so I am writing a set of equations down, and the thing is for whatever reason, the first 2 equations are not indented in, while the rest are indented onto the right. Is there something wrong with my code?

```latex
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} 
\cosh x=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}+e^{-x}) \\
 \sinh x=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}-e^{-x}) \\ 
\tanh x &=\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} \\ 
\operatorname{sech} x &=\frac{1}{\cosh x}=\frac{2}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} \\ 
\operatorname{cosech} x &=\frac{1}{\sinh x}=\frac{2}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} \\ 
\operatorname{coth} x &=\frac{1}{\tanh x}=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}
\end{align} 
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: You're missing `&` in the first two lines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, instead of code fragment always provide a small complete document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem and which people can test as it is. With this you will help people who like to help you!

Answer (score 2):

Why not `&` in the first two eqs?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} 
\cosh x&=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}+e^{-x}) \\
 \sinh x&=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}-e^{-x}) \\ 
\tanh x &=\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} \\ 
\operatorname{sech} x &=\frac{1}{\cosh x}=\frac{2}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} \\ 
\operatorname{cosech} x &=\frac{1}{\sinh x}=\frac{2}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} \\ 
\operatorname{coth} x &=\frac{1}{\tanh x}=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}
\end{align} 
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot]